# SwiftUI background does not cover whole HStack

Tags: ios, swiftui, hstack

I have an HStack and it looks like there is some small area above it (white area above the red one) that is kind of not covered by the background. The color of it stays the same no matter which one I use. In dark mode, this area uses the color of the background and that is why not visible but can be detected in debug view.

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    ForEach(sections) { section in
                        Section {
                            PricesFilterMenuSectionView(items: section.items)
                        } header: {
                            Text(section.translation)
                                .font(.title3.weight(.bold))
                                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                .textCase(nil)
                        } footer: {
                            if section != sections.last {
                                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                                    Divider().padding(.top, Layout.dividerTopPadding)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text(title), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: dismissAction, label: { Image(systemName: "xmark").foregroundColor(.primary) }))

/////// This HStack
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        sections.forEach { section in
                            section.items.forEach { item in
                                item.isSelected = false
                            }
                        }
                    }, label: {
                        Text("clear_filters".localized).foregroundColor(ThemeManager.current.secondaryColor.color)
                    })

                    Spacer()

                    Button {
                        let tags = sections.flatMap { section in
                            section.items.compactMap { item -> Int? in
                                item.isSelected ? item.id : nil
                            }
                        }

                        showAction(tags)
                    } label: {
                        Text("show_results".localized)
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(PrimaryButtonStyle())
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, Layout.ctaStackHorizontalPadding)
                .padding(.top)
                .background((colorScheme == .dark ? Color(UIColor.red) : Color.red).ignoresSafeArea())
                .compositingGroup()
//                .shadow(color: colorScheme == .dark ? .black : .gray, radius: 15, x: 0, y: 0)
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: simulator]
[image: debug view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the line after `NavigationView {`

Change this:

```swift
VStack {
```

to this:

```swift
VStack(spacing: 0) {
```